# A foreign key connecting three tables

Tags: foreign-keys

I have found similar questions in this forum, but any of them could bring my mind to a solution, so I thought that somebody could know the answer.

I have this database scenario:

merchandises, suppliers and orders. These are tables, and I have another two tables: orders_merchandises and suppliers_merchandises.

these tables are like this:

```
merchandises
 -id
 -name

suppliers
 -id
 -name

orders
 -id
 -supplier_id

orders_merchandises
 -order_id
 -merchandise_id

suppliers_merchandises
 -supplier_id
 -merchandise_id
```

The rule is:

The suppliers can supply only merchandises that they are able to. So, I have the table suppliers_merchandises to register each suppliers for the merchandises that they supply to the store.

So the orders must restrict suppliers to supply only merchandises "pre-recorded" in the suppliers_merchandises.

I hope that I could explain clear enough.

So, I need a foreign key for multiple tables, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE suppliers_merchandises
ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_NAME (supplier_id, merchandise_id)
REFERENCES (orders.supplier_id, orders_merchandises.merchandise_id)
```

But, unhapply that not works.

Anybody knows if are there any way to do what I want to do?

It can be in any dbms. SQLServer, Firebird, or any other

Answer (score 1):

Use composite keys and relationships:

- Add a `supplier_id` column to `orders_merchandises`
- Make a FK from `orders_merchandises` to `order` on `(order_id, supplier_id)`
- Create a FK from `orders_merchandises` to `supplier_merchandises`on `(supplier_id, merchandise_id)`

This will lock orders from suppliers to only be for merchandise found for them in supplier_merchandise.

You may want to change primary keys from surrogates to composites, and discard existing competing FKs.